# Searchkick::InvalidQueryError 400 error running elasticsearch/searchkick in cloud9?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I run elastic search in cloud9 with the command

```
./elasticsearch -E http.port=8081
```

i then check the status by running curl

```
 curl 127.0.0.1:8081
```

It returns

```
{
  "name" : "JgfOdbe",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "zELSmBAIStOB1VNaOz1C-Q",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.1.1",
    "build_hash" : "bd92e7f",
    "build_date" : "2017-12-17T20:23:25.338Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.1.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Now i create book scaffold and create few books

In books controller i create a test method

```
def index
    @books = Book.search("test", fields: [:title])
end
```

When i call index action it returns the error

```
Searchkick::InvalidQueryError in BooksController#index
```

I have pasted below the error image

[image]

I wonder the reason for this error. It seems the syntax is right. I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are two problems that you need to fix:

#### Configure the Elasticsearch endpoint

Since you're using a different port (8081) than the default (9200), you should set the `ELASTICSEARCH_URL` environment variable to that port:

```
ENV["ELASTICSEARCH_URL"] = "http://localhost:8081"
```

The documentation about that is here: https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#deployment

#### Importing your data

After that, you need to get the data from your models to Elasticsearch, by reindexing it with:

```
Book.reindex
```

The docs are also here: https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#getting-started

Answer (score 0):

The reindex has to be made from the class, not from the object.

When the reindex runs from object some information such as analyzer wasn't created and this exception is thrown.

```
# Works!
Book.reindex

# Not works :(
Book.limit(1000).offset(0).each { |book| book.reindex }
```

See more [here](http://www.sampierson.com/articles/elasticsearch-and-rails-analyzer-searchkick_search-not-found).